# Failed to Convert Edge Data Network X

Tags: string, networking, graph, networkx, readfile

I have this small-gephiready.tsv file that structured like this:

```
Source  Target     Type
1         2     Undirected
1         3     Undirected
1         4     Undirected
1         5     Undirected
1         6     Undirected
```

I want to open it via NetworkX in python environment, with code:

`G = nx.read_edgelist("small-gephiready.tsv", nodetype=int)`

However, it returns error "Failed to convert edge data (['Type']) to dictionary". I thought Type datas is string, so I added `data=('Type',str)` after nodetype=int, and it returns str has no attribute decode.

Am I write the read_edge function wrong or there is something I have to checked in file? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer, that apparently if you give headers for a file, you need some parameters to read them. However, I need pandas read_csv function and toss it to network_x with from_pandas_edgelist function.

```
f = pd.read_csv("small-gephiready.tsv", sep='\t')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(f, source='FromNodeId', target='ToNodeId')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, how it worked, but the below code seemed to have provided me with expected results:

Remove the Headers first, then use the below code

```
nx.read_edgelist("small-gephiready.tsv", nodetype=int, data=(("Type", str),))
```

It loaded the nodes and edges without any issue.